# MYSQL EXPLAIN Query rows showing value as 1 . How?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

```
mysql > EXPLAIN pk_user_id, username from user where pk_user_id = xyz;

+----------+----------
|   rows   | filtered |
+----------+----------+
|    1     |  100.00  |
+----------+-----------
```

Indexing that is being used.

```
PRIMARY -- pk_user_id
```

user table has around 4 million record how is it finding result by scanning one row?

Is it using some kind of map and how is filtered related to rows?

Comment: It is not scanning.  It is using an index lookup and going directly to the xyz row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff upto how many rows it can create index lookup ? or will it not matter a/q to the size of table

Comment: . . Any number of rows.  The size of the table doesn't matter.  It will always return one row with a unique index and should be pretty fast.

Comment: *"Is it using some kind of map..?"* YES, the "map" is a `unique index`, and because it is unique it needs only one row to find `xyz`

Comment: Please study "database indexing".